# What is the easiest way to make a common implementation for system protocol optional requirement in swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

Here's the system protocol and the optional requirement.

```
public protocol WKNavigationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
}
```

Say there are multiple ViewControllers that needs to implement this protocol.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate { } // default
class ViewController2: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate { } // default

class ViewController3: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate { 

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print("Override Success!")
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could provide a default implementation for this protocol if it's not implemented in the ViewControllers just as we would for a custom protocol.

```
extension WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print("Success!") // default implementation doesn't seem to work for system protocol
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this has already been asked here before. I couldn't find anything specific to my query :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the base class `UIViewController` and conform it to the system protocol `WKNavigationDelegate` with the default implementation

```
extension UIViewController : WKNavigationDelegate  {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print("Success!")
    }
}
```

and override it in subclasses

Comment: Caused redundant conformance error in so many places, removed all of them (hope there won't be any issues related to that). Also, added `override` for places that required an override and finally it worked. Thanks!